# How do I add google capcha to this website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Contact Form

```
<section id="contact" class="contact-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="section-title text-center pb-20">
                    <h3 class="title">Get in touch</h3>
                  
                </div> <!-- section title -->
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="contact-two mt-50 wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <h4 class="contact-title">Lets talk about the project</h4>
                   
                    <ul class="contact-info">
                      
                       <li> <a class="skype" href=""> <i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i> SKYPE  (Chat)</a></li>
                       <li><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="">WhatsApp</a></li>
                       <li><i class="lni-phone-handset"></i>123456789</li>
                        <li><i class="lni-envelope"></i> sample@gmail.com </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- contact two -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="contact-form form-style-one mt-35 wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <form  id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                        <div class="form-input mt-15">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <div class="input-items default">
                                <input id="name-input"  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full name" required>
                                <i class="lni-user"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- form input -->
                        <div class="form-input mt-15">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <div class="input-items default">
                                <input id="email-input"  name="email" type="text" placeholder="Eg. example@email.com" required>
                                <i class="lni-envelope"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- form input -->
                        <div class="form-input mt-15">
                            <label>Massage</label>
                            <div class="input-items default">
                                <textarea id="message-textarea" name="message" placeholder="Write us a message"></textarea>
                                <i class="lni-pencil-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- form input -->
                    
                        
                        <p class="form-message"></p>
                        <div class="form-input rounded-buttons mt-20">
                            <button class="main-btn rounded-three" id="btnSend" onclick="submitForm();">Send message</button>
                        </div> <!-- form input -->
                    </form>
                    
                    <div id="successDiv" >
                        <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:12px; padding-top:10px;">Thank you!</h1>
                        <h4 style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:green">Your message has been successfully sent. We will contact you very soon!</h4>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- contact form -->
            </div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
</section>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
        $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
            $('document').ready(function(){
            $("#successDiv").fadeOut();
        });
        function submitForm()
        {
            var name = $("#name-input").val();
            var email = $("#email-input").val();
            var msg = $("#message-textarea").val();
      
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST", 
                   url: "http://vrnl.net/contactfrm.php",
                   data: {name:name,email:email,msg:msg},
                   success:function(response){
                       if($.trim(response)=="Success")
                       {
                            // $("#successDiv").css("display","block");
                               $("#successDiv").fadeIn();
                            setTimeout(function (){ $("#successDiv").fadeOut(); },2000);
                            $("#name-input").val("");
                            $("#email-input").val("");
                            $("#message-textarea").val("");
                            
                           
                       }
                       else
                       {}
                         
                   }
                });
            
            
        }
        
    </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
//get data from form  
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['msg'];
$to = "sample@gmail.com";
$subject = "Mail From website";
$cc = "sample@gmail.com";
$txt ="";
$txt .="<html><body>";
$txt .= "<table style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 30%; background: #ddd7d769;'><tr>
<th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Name</th>";
$txt .= "<td  style='  border: 1px solid #0000004f;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>".$name."</td></tr>";
$txt .= "<tr style='background: lightgrey;'><th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Email</th>";
$txt .= "<td style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$email."</td></tr>";
$txt .= "<tr><th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Message</th>";
$txt .= "<td style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$message."</td></tr>";
$txt .= "</table>";
$txt .="</body></html>";


$headers = "From: vrnl.net" . "\r\n" ;

$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL'\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

if($email!=NULL){
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    echo "Success";
}
else{
    echo "Fail";
}
//redirect
// echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

I want to add a google capcha for this enquiry form.

On clicking submit button, if capcha is not entered, it should throw an error. I've been getting spammed by bots and spent whole day searching for google capcha but got nothing working for this code.

I have sitekey and secret key for my website, I also tried adding the capcha before "Send Message" button. Capcha does show there but it does not validate on click.

Comment: There is no captcha in your code. Have you read [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/)

Comment: Yes I have read about it, I wrote I tried adding it but it didn't work,  this code doesn't have it because I dont know where and how to add it. Thats why I raised a question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Insert code inside <form> element.
    <form method="post">
        <?php
        require once('recaptchalib.php');
        $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

Note: Don't forget to set $publickey by replacing your_public_key with your API public key. You can get from https://developers.google.com/recaptcha
```

Comment: Code only answers are not as helpful. Please think about adding some sort of context to your answer.